# Invalidating a Timer created multiple times

Tags: swift, nstimer

I am trying to invalidate a `Timer` which is created multiple times in a class. Firstly I create a global Timer;

```
var musicTimer: Timer?
```

And I initiate it.

```
self.musicTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
    timeInterval: 2.0,
    target: self,
    selector: #selector(startMusicOnCorrectTime),
    userInfo: nil,
    repeats: true)
```

Then somehow I need to invalidate the timer because I need to stop calling a function.

```
self.musicTimer?.invalidate()
```

And then I need to recreate this timer with the same parameters.

```
self.musicTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
    timeInterval: 2.0,
    target: self,
    selector: #selector(startMusicOnCorrectTime),
    userInfo: nil,
    repeats: true)
```

But this time when I need to invalidate it, I cannot. During the class lifecycle, I need this sequence multiple times and the amount is not exact.

Comment: What do you mean by "you cannot"? Is there an error message or anything like that? Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: I know that invalidated timers cannot be used again, so, what I am asking is how can I invalidate re-created timer.

Comment: What error do you get when you try to invalidate the 2nd instance?

Comment: there is no error, the timer is not being invalidated. It just goes on working.

Comment: You need to post code that makes the issue reproducible or at least better explains the the events leading up to this issue.

Comment: From the code you have posted, the problem is not visible. I assume you do not invalidate the timer correctly and it is still around. But without more relevant code I can't tell what the root of your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without a full code example, but here's an idea. In case you are calling `invalidate` from a different thread than you started it on (e.g. you start it on the main thread but invalidate it on a background thread), it won't work according to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1415405-invalidate):

> You must send this message from the thread on which the timer was installed. If you send this message from another thread, the input source associated with the timer may not be removed from its run loop, which could prevent the thread from exiting properly.